# How can I offload Object3d.toJSON() operation to a web worker?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I need to convert the active scene in threejs to json object. But as the models become bigger, the process takes more and more time. I can't even show a progress bar for the same. I tried to send the threejs scene to a web worker and convert it to json at the worker. But I wasn't able to send the scene object to the worker. Is it possible to send the threejs scene to web worker? Or is there any promise based implementation for the `Object3d.toJSON()`?

Comment: A promise-based solution wouldn't help you, it would just put the delay elsewhen (sic). I suggest rephrasing your question: "How can I either offload the `Object3d.toJSON` operation to a web worker or break it into smaller parts so the browser remains responsive while it's happening?"

Comment: @T.JCrowder, How can I convert scene to json without sending the scene object to the worker?  Here I can't send the scene object to the worker? can you suggest any methods?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible to send the threejs scene to web worker?

not really. Data-Exchange with the worker is limited to ArrayBuffers and anything that can be copied over using the structured clone algorithm. It's very likely, that it won't even work for something like a THREE.Scene object. But, whatever you try, something in the same complexity order as toJSON() needs to take place to get everything into the Worker.

> Or is there any promise based implementation for the Object3d.toJSON()?

unfortunately nothing that could make it behave in a way that doesn't block the UI thread for however long it takes.

But you can have a look at what exactly consumes most of the time ([do you have huge texture-images maybe?](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/src/textures/Texture.js#L217-L220)) and find a way to spot-optimize these things by just overwriting `THREE.Whatever.prototype.toJSON()` with an alternative version.

Comment: Yes, I have some huge textures. I am trying to modify the toJSON() to avoid the export of images to json. ;) Thanks for the response.