# How to loading furniture the data3d.buffer of the local request?

Tags: archilogic, 3d.io

I downloaded the furniture data3d.buffer and some image files to the local server. Do not want the product model to connect to storage.3d.io. But loading the local data3d.buffer shows an error.

browser error:

```
File header error: Wrong magic number. File is probably not data3d buffer format. decode-binary.js:71:4

File header error: Wrong version number: 0. Parser supports version: 1

RangeError: "attempting to construct out-of-bounds TypedArray on ArrayBuffer" 

RangeError: "invalid or out-of-range index"
```

How can i to download the furniture related files to the local and loading to 3d engines.
and I use open source for 3dio-js to study.

Thank you.

Comment: seems like you somehow screwed up the file.
we can only give support for using the 3d.io furniture library via our api.
but like in every a-frame scene, you can always add your own geometries.

Comment: try to unzip the data3d.buffer files and remove ".gz." from the filenames, if present. (data.buffer files are being served gzipped. browser does unzip it transparently. but depending on how you downloaded them, they might still be gzipped which could cause the error)

Comment: how to unzip the data3d.buffer files and remove '.gz.' from the filename ?

Comment: Please look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51764218/aframe-orbit-controls-does-not-work-on-3dio-js .Thank you.