# aframe : orbit-controls does not work on 3dio.js

Tags: archilogic, 3d.io

How to solve the problem for orbit-control does not work on 3dio.js?

[image]

This website example of code is: 
https://glitch.com/edit/#!/silk-teeth

Thank you.

Comment: can you please provide the example code in https://glitch.com/ or http://jsfiddle.net/ ? that would help a lot

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve].  This post also explains why you should not post images of code: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: Ok, Thanks, @tomaspolach This website example of code is: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/silk-teeth

Comment: @tomaspolach can you check the code for me？

Comment: in line 66 you reset the camera to look-controls
that's why orbit-controls is not working.
please ask the author of this component for further support

Comment: @Frederic, Thanks, I comment out the code, but I still did not work. If I don't use API, it works normally. Can you help me solve this problem? Thank you very much.